# One who is repulsed by / dislikes something

Tags: nouns

What would you call someone who dislikes, say, the taste of chocolate?  They have a non-preference for it.

'-phobe' doesn't seem to fit as it implies they want it to suffer or be destroyed, or they are frightened of it.

'antiphile' isn't a word and neither is 'contraphile'.

The closest similar question I've found was '[the opposite of -phile](https://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070422022022AAUwusZ)'.

EDIT:
As mentioned by @ermanen there is a very similar question: [Is there a suffix for loathing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58508/is-there-a-suffix-for-loathing)

I was not necessarily after a suffix and was looking for an 'identity' term.  EG: A person who dislikes the taste of chocolate and is quite secure in and not embarrassed by it.  This person does not bear ill will to those that do like the taste of chocolate.

Comment: *Hater* of the taste of chocolate.

Answer (score 4):

***'Chocolate averse'*** or ***'Chocolate-averse'*** might be candidates.

An example from 'The Local Fr' website (http://www.thelocal.fr/20110829/986):

> *Oscar Franco and colleagues from the University of Cambridge reviewed half a dozen studies covering 100,000 patients, with and without heart disease, comparing the group that consumed the most and the least chocolate in each.*
>
> *They found that the highest level of chocolate intake was associated with a 37 percent reduction in cardiovascular disease, and a 20 percent drop in strokes, when compared with the **chocolate-averse** cohort.*
>
> *No significant reduction was reported in the incidence of heart attack.*

The original article from Oscar Franco is published and available on the British Medical Journal online site: http://www.bmj.com/content/343/bmj.d4488

The modifier *'-averse'* is perhaps most commonly seen in the combination *'risk-averse'*, and in associated business jargon word combinations such as *'Loss averse'* and *'Change averse'*.

Averse is an old word, from the Latin 'to turn away', and not to be confused with *'adverse'*.  From the Oxford English Dictionary:

> averse ▪ I.averse, a. and n.
>   (əˈvɜːs)
>   Also 7 avers.
>   [ad. L. āversus, pa. pple. of āvertĕre to avert. Cf. OF. avers, in which L. āversus and adversus seem to have combined.]
>   A. adj.
>   1. Turned away, averted; turned in the backward or reverse direction. Obs.
>   *1682 Sir T. Browne Chr. Mor. 90 Two faces averse, and conjoined Janus-like. 1697 Dryden Virgil (1806) III. 274 The tracks averse a lying notice gave. 1703 Rowe Fair Penit. i. i. 109 With looks averse and Eyes that froze me.*
>
> 4  Turned away in mind or feeling; actuated by repugnance; habitually opposed, disinclined.
>   *1597 Daniel Civ. Wares i. xxvi, And of a spirit averse, and overthwart. 1671 Milton Samson 1461 Some much averse I found and wondrous harsh. 1744 Harris Three Treat. iii. ii. (1765) 233 That Law..which leads the Willing, and compels the Averse.*
>
> c. with inf. Disinclined, unwilling, reluctant.
>   *1646 Sir T. Browne Pseud. Ep. iv. viii. 198 We are not averse to acknowledge, that some may distill..into the winde-pipe. 1777 Watson Philip II (1793) II. xii. 83 Averse at this time to declare herself openly. 1864 R. Burton Dahome 8 Even the grass is, from idless, averse to wave.*

The combination *'-averse'* appears to be a modern construction:

[image]

From Google's Ngram tool (http://preview.tinyurl.com/qz95r6u). Noting that Ngrams consider paired words such as *'risk averse'* equivalent to hyphenated words such as *'risk-averse'*.

Answer (score 0):

About Dutch-process cocoa, Sara Perry writes, "Advocates say the chocolate flavor is more well-rounded; *detractors* call it dull."

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, **hater** might work in informal contexts.

> Statistically speaking, the number of people who love chocolate
>   appears to dwarf that of those who hate it. However, **chocolate haters**
>   exist, and the problems they face in this chocolate-crazed world are
>   very real.

(http://www.sheknows.com/food-and-recipes/articles/1072831/things-only-people-who-hate-chocolate-will-understand)

Another example could be **milk hater**, a term well-understood by moms:

> The Perfect Milk for your **Milk Hater** in the house

(http://www.thehungryhousewife.com/2014/02/the-prefect-milk-for-your-milk-hater-in-the-house.html)

> Solutions for **Milk Haters**

(http://www.parenting.com/article/solutions-for-milk-haters)