# What do you call someone who hates pictures?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning-in-context

What do you call a person who hates pictures, drawings, photos, and images of all kinds and finds them unnecessary and uninteresting. I found a word iconoclast to have a similar meaning, but it had a strong religious colour. I'm not talking about people who hates their pictures taken. I'm taking about people who don't like pictures in general.

Comment: I'd likely coin a word like "picturephobe" or "graphicphobe".  Slightly more formal would be "graphics averse" or "graphics abhorrent".

Comment: English paintings were destroyed in great numbers by the Puritans during the Civil War; but they also hated dances, theatre, fairs, and holidays.

Comment: It's not a *fear* suffix we're looking for here, it's a *hate* suffix. "Antipictatorial" or similar, if that were a real word.

Comment: This is *some* help: Is there a suffix for loathing? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58508/is-there-a-suffix-for-loathing

Comment: It looks like, someone has to come up with a neologism. Until then OP can use "aversion to the images [*of type*]"

Comment: *moron* comes to mind...

Answer (score 1):

An *iconoclast* is, in its literal sense, someone who **breaks** images. The word derives from Greek εἰκών *eikōn* ‘image’ (also ‘shape’, ‘form’) and the verb κλάω *klaō* ‘break’ and literally means an image breaker.

As you’ve noted, though, the word is very heavily religiously laden, and moreover it’s mostly used in an extended, figurative sense, referring to someone who challenges (especially religious) views and principles.

There is a more appropriate formation also based on εἰκών, with the more familiar *-phobe* suffix, namely an **iconophobe**.

This is hardly a common word, but it is used. Wikipedia has an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconophobia) on it, which describes it thus in its opening lines:

> **Iconophobia** (literally *fear of icons*) refers to an aversion to images, especially religious icons. *Iconophobia* is differentiated from *iconoclasm* in that *iconophobia* refers to the aversion to or hatred of the images whereas *iconoclasm* refers to the actual destruction of images that may arise from iconophobia.

This is still a word with close ties to religion and religious philosophy. If you are going to use it in a written piece, you would be well-advised to specify if you’re using it in a non-religious context to refer to someone who just dislikes images in general.

Answer (score 0):

Their attitude might be described as "**austere**" pertaining to pictures, and possibly other images, decorations, or adornments as well. They prefer life to be lived and represented as "plain" and "real" rather than as any form of "ancillary" or "artificial" representation. Pictures probably seem like contrived images to them.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/austere

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/plain

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/real

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/artificial

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ancillary

Comment: All these words are far too broad to answer the question; they are not related to images, just adjectives that could be used to describe someone with this outlook.

Comment: Actually @Janus, I was only suggesting "austere", but I thought highlighting the others made it clearer. An austere person does not have to be "severe" as some definitions might suggest. I'm sorry the word didn't match your expectations.

Answer (score -1):

> Iconoclam is the social belief in the importance of the description of icons and other images or monuments, most frequently for religious or political reasons. People who engage in or support iconoclasm are called iconoclasts, a term that has come to be applied figuratively to any individual who challenges "cherished beliefs or venerated institutions on the grounds that they are erroneous or pernicious."

It's the current figurative use of the word iconoclast applied that I would only recommend using because it's the only one most English speakers understand (and that's only true amongst college educated English speakers). The word, even in its figurative sense has only a very low word frequency use among intellectuals,  and I'd say virtually is never used in English in its non-figurative sense. So I'll stand by my statement that I have never heard of a single word in English for a person who „hates, pictures, drawings, photos, etc and finds them unnecessary and uninteresting.“

Comment: There is no single word I`ve ever heard of in English to describe a person like this.

Comment: There's a line in Mario Klarer's 'an introduction to literary studies' 3rd edition page 2. It says:" the medieval union of word and picture, in which both components of the text formed a single, harmonious entity, slowly disappeared. This modern iconoclasm (i.e., hostility toward pictures) not only restricts the visual dimensions of texts but also sees writing as a medium that can function with little connection to the acoustic element of language."

Comment: See my comments below. No one uses iconoclast in its non-figurative original sense. Quoting esoteric books no one but PhD English Literature candidates would read is not helpful for an English learner.

Comment: This should really be a comment, IMO

Comment: English learners need to first start with commonly used phrases and words, and if none exist in the ordinary vernacular, the inquiry should stop there. Once they reach an advanced level in English, they won`t be coming to a board like this asking for help. Steering them in the direction of esoteric books for PhD students or striving to find obscure definitions no one has ever heard of in English is not helpful to a learner.

Comment: [_**English Language & Usage Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts._](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: A comment?  It´s an observation perhaps to help the person asking for assistance. This board attracts people who have a variety of questions about Englsh usage. If the person is a native speaker asking an esoteric question for a dissertation, that´s fine. But, I think most are here to learn real English that is written in books, journals and is spoken on the street. To point out a word no one would ever use in English outside a PhD program in English at Harvard is likely not helpful, unless the OP specifically identifies the question as seeking this sort of answer. The OP did not suggest this.

Comment: No, it's the purpose of this site.

Comment: As side note, what you call _my comments below_ are really answers. On a Stack Exchange site, an answer is not a comment. What you post in _Your answer_ is an answer, whose purpose is not replying to other comments, as you did.

Comment: This, too, should be a comment. Welcome to stackexchange, John. Please, [read the FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @John This site is specifically **not** geared towards English learners. We have a different site for that, [ell.se]. This site is precisely where esoteric word usage is relevant as an answer.

Comment: Is exchanging [quotation marks in the German tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#History) for [conventional English practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_marks_in_English#Orthographical_considerations) considered a constructive edit on this stack? I am not picking on John. I've seen this a few times and wasn't sure whether to change it during my other edits.

Comment: For description, did you mean to say 'destruction'?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/329536)